# Is it possible to run game from another PC on my PC?

Tags: windows, gaming

I have a PC and a laptop. My PC is weak, but it has enough storage to download the game I need.

Is it possible to run my game on a laptop while keeping it on my PC's HDD?

Comment: Can this be done? Absolutely.  Will it be worse than Nvidia GeForce Now, Absolutely, since none of the applications that you can use for these, are designed to do that, with the exception of Steam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a network share in the weak PC that will externalize
this disk space.

In the strong PC, you could connect-to and map this network share
and give it a drive letter.

You can then use that drive in the strong PC in order to install the game
and play it. Note that using a drive over the network is slow, so not
every game is suitable to this setup.